# facing issue in creating bot channel where microsoft.botservice already registered in resource provider

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

I have registered to one month free subscription of azure and when i want to create bot channel registration it shows resource provider botservice not registered.

[image]

when i search in resource provider the botservice is already registered
[image]

do anyone know how to overcome this issue and can create botchannel

Comment: Please follow the below link for this error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-register-resource-provider

Answer (score 0):

We are able to create the bot channel registration in azure portal successfully. If you are still facing an issue you can raise a support request in the azure portal to work with an engineer.